# can't decompress .tgz using gunzip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar, gzip

I was able to archive and compress a folder with the following command:

```
tar -cvfz example2.tgz example1
```

I then removed the example1 folder and tried to unpack the archive using this command:

```
tar -xvfz example2.tgz
```

and tried

```
tar -zxvf example2.tgz
```

Niether of these commands worked. The error returned was:

```
gzip: example2.tgz: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

It clearly used gzip compression since I passed tar the `z` qualifier in the initial command. What am I doing wrong? I am on Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: Minor comment. You wrote `tar -cvfz example2.tgz example1`. Aside from the syntax issue (as others have said, flag order is significant here), did you really mean to write `example1` there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you're showing in your first line (`tar -cvfz example2.tgz example1`) doesn't work and it should not output any file `example2.tgz`. Didn't you get an error? Perhaps the file `example2.tgz` existed already? Check if you have a file called `z` in that folder - that's where the tgz has been saved to, because:

The `-f` parameter specifies the file which must follow immediately afterwards: `-f <file>`

Try

```
tar cvzf exam.tgz example1
```

Comment: No, on initial creation I did not get any errors and the example2.tgz file was placed into my home directory. I did not already have a file with that name. What is *max*.dat and what does it do?

Comment: well that just went away that's strange

Comment: that was a unintential copy paste error on my side, it's corrected already.

Comment: can you confirm you have a file `z` in your folder?

Comment: I did have some z files in there. They only showed up after I ran the extraction command with subsequent failures. However, after following your instructions and placing the "f" param last in the sequence, I can now unzip the .tgz file. Thanks for the help Sebastian :)

Comment: Just to make things more confusing, in order to be compatible with historical implementations, GNU tar and IIRC a few others parse `tar cvfz exam.tgz example1` as creating a compressed archive `exam.tgz`, but `tar -cvfz exam.tgz example1` creates a plain tar archive `z` containing `exam.tgz` and `example1`. The reason is that the original `tar` implementation didn't use what has now become the standard for command line switches, and instead used its first argument as a block of switches.

Answer (score 2):

just to precise, **creation**

```
tar cvzf example2.tgz example1
```

**extraction**

```
tar xvzf example2.tgz
```

where

- c : create
- x : extract
- v : verbose
- z : compress
- f : target tar/tar gz file argument, sould be placed last

the trick is that f is expecting a file, which should be next.

Comment: yeah, my Linux study guides fail to mention that small but crucial detail lol